# Android - Draw on Canvas relative to pixel density

Tags: android, canvas

So I'm trying to draw text and a stroked circle but they look different on different sized devices with different pixel densities.

I'm already multiplying the text size and stroke width ( `Paint.setStrokeWidth()` ) with `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`. I already tried inverting it too ( `1 / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` ) and then multiplying the text size and stroke width with the inverted density. How can I make them look physically the same on all devices?

Comment: try `TypedValue#applyDimension(int unit, float value, DisplayMetrics metrics)` with `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` and use the returned value for setting the text size

Comment: Only the text size? What about the stroke width? And for that matter any other dimension?

Comment: stroke width is not important for `Paint.Style.FILL` (the default one)

Comment: I said i',m trying to make a **stroked** circle.

Comment: ok so use `applyDimension` twice, with `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` and `COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `dimens` with `dp` for stroke width and `sp` for text size and let Android SDK do the rest.

In your `dimens.xml` (exemplary values):

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="your_stroke_width">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="your_text_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

In your code:

```
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_stroke_width));

mTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.your_text_size));
```